# Show how $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{(1)^n}{ln\left(n+1\right)}$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{(1)^n}{\ln\left(n+1\right)}$$

I've tried using Ratio Test as it seems to be the most obvious but it doesn't work.

edit: actually it should be $1^n $ which is just 1. It was just a part of a question where I had to sub in x = 1 & x = -1 to find whether the end point converges or diverges.
sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: What is the significance of $1^n$?

Comment: Maybe he'll @Regret putting that superscript. ;)

Comment: should it be $(-1)^n$ ?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$\ln(n+1)\leq n+1\implies \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}\geq\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: nice you can simplify 1/n+1 into a HPS to prove it diverges

Comment: I think that $1^n$ should be reedited in the question as $(-1)^n$ (and it is more interesting this way)

Comment: @Thomas, problem is: if you edit in that way, the series converges and the question seemed to be show that "..." diverges.

Comment: ah shit. Well the power-n introduced some serious doubts here. I will cancel the edit

Answer (score 1):

First of all the series must start from $n=1$. If you have $(-1)^{n}$ at numerator the series converges for the alternating series test http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test, and its sum is $-0.92429...$ If you have $1^{n}=1$ at numerator, the series diverges because $$\underset{n\geq1}{\sum}\frac{1}{n}\leq\underset{n\geq1}{\sum}\frac{1}{\log\left(n+1\right)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the question is about $1^n$ or $(-1)^n$ but in the latter case :

Hint: you have to group terms by two : $\sum \frac{1}{\ln(2n)} - \frac{1}{\ln(2n+1)}$.

Then use the $O()$ notation and express $\ln(2n+1)$ in terms of $\ln(2n)$ and $O(\frac{1}{n})$

This should lead you to $\sum O(\frac{1}{n\ln(n)})$. If you are not familiar with this notation I will answer more